# Generating function from symmetric group and combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I am looking for the analytic formula for the following expression:

$$f_{n}(x,y)=\sum_{g\in S_{n}}x^{\chi(g)}y^{\chi(g\tau)}$$
where $g$ is taken from the permutation group $S_n$ the exponent () are number of cycles in the cycle notation of  the cyclic permutation.

I have tried to use Mathematica to predict the general from the coefficients but no success.
Probably the way to solve is using Polya's enumeration theorem, but I am not familiar with the topic.

Comment: the cyclic permutation is $(123\cdots n)$?

Comment: yes, so  it puts 1 in the end and shift each letter forward.